# Is it possible to retrieve all posts with a certain value for metadata?

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, meta-query

Under 4.5, I have posts with `meta_key` as *series* and `meta_value` as *19, 20, etc*

I am trying to loop through them in a template, and I guess I'm a special kind of dense.

Most recently I have tried

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'series',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'series',
    'meta_query' => [
        'key' => 'series',
        'value' => 19,
        'compare' => '=',
    ],
];

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It seems to return empty objects, or a result of one, depending on what I change.

Is there some trick to looping through, maybe?

Comment: Are these values serialized? As in, did you save an array of values? I'm not sure if it matters but are they strings or integers? '19' and 19 may be different in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your custom post type is also "series".
Can you try this, it should work.

```
 $args = [
        'post_type' => 'series',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => [
            [
            'key' => 'series',
            'value' => 19,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'=>'NUMERIC'
            ]
        ],
    ];

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

or you can simple use:

```
$args = [
            'post_type' => 'series',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'=>'series',
            'meta_value'=>19,
            'meta_compare'=>'=',
            'meta_type'=>'NUMERIC'
        ];

        $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you are using these meta values as NUMERIC it will be essential to provide "meta_type", as WordPress treats "Numeric" and "Char" values very differently. As you seems to use these value as Number, you need to provide "meta_type"

Comment: I think `meta_query` takes an array of arrays: `meta_query => array( array() )`. Could you also explain what you did and why?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, yes! let me edit it.